# Using with() in Spot ORM

Tags: php, orm

I'm using [Spot ORM](http://phpdatamapper.com/) for a side project. In the documentation it is written

> All relation types are lazy-loaded by default, and can be eager-loaded to solve the N+1 query problem using the with method:
>
> `$posts = $posts->all()->with('comments');`

However, the Entity does not have this method, and I can only find it in the Mapper class, but it is protected (And thus unavailable). How am I supposed to implement eager loading ?

Comment: If it's protected it doesn't mean it's unavailable. If the class you're refering to is `abstract` you'll have to extend from it.

Comment: [It is not](https://github.com/vlucas/spot2/blob/master/lib/Spot/Mapper.php) :( Also, the [documentation](http://phpdatamapper.com/docs/relations/#Eager_Loading) makes it read like it can be used out of the box

Comment: On which class do you want to use the `with()` function? I assume not the `Mapper` class, since you pointed out it was the only one to have the functions.

Comment: That is actually my question, on which class am I supposed to use it ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In general

---

From the [documentation](http://phpdatamapper.com/docs/mappers/):

> Since Spot follows the DataMapper design pattern, you will need a mapper instance for working with object Entities and database tables.
>
> Mappers only work with one entity type, so you will need one mapper per entity class you work with (i.e. to save an Entity\Post, you will need the appropriate mapper, and to save an Entity\Comment, you will need a comment mapper, not the same post mapper. Relations will automatically be loaded and handled by their corresponding mapper by Spot.

This means you will have to use the `Mapper` class for your entities.

> Although you do not have to create a mapper for each entity, sometimes it is nice to create one if you have a lot of custom finder methods, or want a better place to contain the logic of building all the queries you need.

This means you can create your own `Mapper` extensions (not required), if you need specific functionality. Unless you need specific logic such as finder methods or other custom logic, Spot will load the generic mapper for you and return it.

So use your own, or the generic, `Mapper` and use the `with()` method from there. Please note that a protected field does *not* mean it's unavailable. It just means that classes who have `Mapper` as their parent also get the `with()` method, while the `with()` method remains "private" so it can't be reached outside of the class.
As specified in the class you linked the `with()` method is protected, with the following comments:

```
 /**
* Eager-load associations for an entire collection
*
* @internal Implementation may change... for internal use only
*/
```

You can see that it is specified for internal use only. Note that this doesn't mean it can't be used, it can, but only *inside* the `Mapper` class. There are other methods inside the `Mapper` class that use the `with()`

#### Your quote

---

The specific part you linked to seems to be contradictory since it looks like it refers to an `Entity`, but what I think is going on there is that it is a custom `Mapper`.

If you consider this as your `Post` `Entity`:

```
namespace Entity;
class PostEntity extends \Spot\Entity
{
    protected static $mapper = 'Entity\Mapper\PostMapper';
    // ... snip ...
}
```

And have another one that extends from `Mapper`:

```
namespace Entity\Mapper;
use Spot\Mapper;
class PostMapper extends Mapper
{

    //other methods

    //example method
    /**
    * Get 10 most recent posts for display on the sidebar
    *
    * @return \Spot\Query
    */
    public function mostRecentPostsForSidebar()
    {
        return $this->where(['status' => 'active'])
            ->order(['date_created' => 'DESC'])
            ->limit(10);
    }

    //other methods
}
```

You have now extended from `Mapper`, so now you have the `with()` method available to you.
In the `PostMapper` you can do something like:

```
//Pseudocode
public function some_method()
{
    //Some code
    $this->with($collection, $entityName, $with);
    //Some code
}
```

Note that you also have the `PostMapper` available to you in the `PostEntity` (as a `static` field). Hope that it's more clear to you now. Maybe they should have specified on that part of the documentation that it was using a custom `Mapper`.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of disappointing, but I'll go with that :D

Comment: this is where nomenclature like ```PostMapper``` would have helped.

Comment: @donquixote Yeah I don't know why I kept those names... I think I must have taken them from their example code and didn't want to mess anything up. I've updated it so it's a bit more clear now hopefully. Thanks for the heads-up.